# How to send several methods to child component in Vue

Tags: vue.js, events, event-listener

I need to pass two methods to my child component. That component is `<NavigationBar/>`, and there i have two `<li>` elements `Field` and `Statistic`. When i click on `Field` i want to execute `pausedMethod(){something=true}`, when i click on `Statistic` i want to execute `resumeMethod(){something=false}`.

I can listen for one event like this `<NavigationBar v-on:click="pauseMethod"/>`, but when i pass another method `<NavigationBar v-on:click="pauseMethod" v-on:click="resumeMethod"/>` i'm getting an error that i'm call two times for `v-on:click`.
How to pass two methods to componenet and how can i listen for both.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can just call two methods in one handler, like that

```js
<NavigationBar v-on:click="pauseMethod(); resumeMethod();" />
```

Or you can create another helper method

```js
<NavigationBar v-on:click="handleClick" />

...

methods: {
   handleClick() {
       this.resumeMethod()
       this.pauseMethod()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in Vue. 
You can use `$emit` to achieve this:

```js
Vue.component("NavigationBar", {
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li @click="pause">Field</li>
      <li @click="resume">Statistics</li>
    </ul>`,
  methods: {
    pause() {
      this.$emit('pause');
    },
    resume() {
      this.$emit('resume');
    },
  }
});
Vue.component("wrapper", {
  template: `<NavigationBar @pause="onPause" @resume="onResume" />`,
  methods: {
    onPause() {
      // Do stuff
      console.log('Paused');
    },
    onResume() {
      // Do stuff
      console.log('Resumed');
    }
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: "#app"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <wrapper/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. I found a solution. Check it out !

- Parent Component

  `<template>
       <Navigation v-on:click="myMethod"/>
  </template>`

  `<script>
  name:'ParentElement',
  data(){
      somethig:true;
  },
  methods:{
  myMethod(result){
      this.somethis=result;
      }
  }
  </script>`
- Child Element

  `<ul>
      <li @click="$emit('click',false)">Fields</li>
      <li @click="$emit('click',true)">Statistics</li>
  </ul>`